# undefined method `upVote_request_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f3aa08b13c0>:0x000056436a5e59a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure what's causing it. Im getting this as a 500 error when my js file runs

```
undefined method `upVote_request_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f3aa08b13c0>:0x000056436a5e59a8>
```

Here's the html

```
<tbody>
    <% @requests.each do |request| %>
      <tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">
        <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.artist %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.title %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center" class="voteCount"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><button class = "voteButton" onclick="upVote()">Vote</button></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Vote', [:upVote, request], remote: true, method: :post, class: 'upVote' %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Here's the method in my controller

```
def upvote
  request = Request.find(params[:id])
  request.upvote! 
  render json: { voteCount: request.voteCount } 
end
```

Here's my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests
  post '/requests:id', to: 'requests#upVote', as: 'Vote'
end
```

And here's my JS method
function upVote() {

```
    var count = document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML;
    count = parseInt(count);
    count = count + 1;
    count = count.toString();
    document.getElementById("voteCount").innerHTML = count;
    document.getElementById("voteButton").disabled = "true";

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just trying to increment a vote column in your Request model without refreshing the page?

If you create a path to your controller method as so;

```
Routes.rb
resources :requests do
  post 'upvote', to: 'requests#upvote'
end
```

You should get a `rake routes` line that looks like this;

```
  request_upvote POST   /requests/:request_id/upvote(.:format)                                                   requests#upvote
```

Then you can simplify the html like so;

```
<td><%= link_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, class: 'upVote' %></td>
```

This just makes it all a simple update action.

In your controller, if your voteCount column is an integer, use the .increment! method on the request and it will increment the record and save it;

```
def upvote
    puts 'upvote'
    request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
    request.increment!(:voteCount)
    render json: { voteCount: request.voteCount }
end
```

EDIT: Because I think I got a better idea of what you were trying to accomplish with the javascript.

It looks like you're using the button to increment the html page and the link to update the actual record, using my suggestion above, you can change the two lines;

```
<td style="text-align: center"><button class = "voteButton" onclick="upVote()">Vote</button></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Vote', [:upVote, request], remote: true, method: :post, class: 'upVote' %></td>
```

into just;

```
  <td><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: 'upVote()', class: 'upVote' %></td>
```

and updating the function;

```
function upVote() {

        var count = document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML;
        count = parseInt(count);
        count = count + 1;
        count = count.toString();
        document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML = count;
        document.getElementsByClassName("upVote")[0].disabled = "true";

    }
```

Obviously, the JS selectors need to be changed so you aren't selecting every request counter on the page and every upVote button unless thats what you want.

Comment: How do I access the Selectors in JS? I'm used to using getElementsById etc.

Comment: it looks like `request_upvote_path(request.id)` is not actually calling the method in my controller. Here's my route output `request_upvote POST   /requests/:request_id/upvote(.:format)   requests#upvote`

Answer (score 0):

`post '/requests', to: 'requests#upVote'` does not define the path you're using

if you want to name that path, you can use the `:as` arg.

run `rake routes` and it will output all of the available routes as defined by your routes.rb, which will help you find the right syntax for your upvote route.

Comment: ok, so I did what you suggested and I'm still getting the error. This is how I set up the routes.rb after reviewing your answer `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests
  post '/requests:id', to: 'requests#upVote', as: 'Vote'
end
`

Comment: post the outcome of `rake routes`

Comment: I changed this around a bit. Here's the outcome of the `rake routes` `request_upvote POST   /requests/:request_id/upvote(.:format) requests#upvote`

Comment: @user9175041 That output suggests your path helper is `request_upvote_path(@request)`